# What happens to Pod-Workload if a Node gets destroyed

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

when running pod-workload on an AKS-cluster with autoscaling enabled, what happens, if the pool gets scaled down? If a Pod is running workload on a node, and this node is being removed because of nodepool-scaledown, how does Kubernetes manage to keep my pod running? Even if there is a re-scheduling, this would interrupt my workload, which would lead to a failure in my case.

So how does K8s know, when a Node is "ready" to be scaled down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a node is being gracefully removed then Kubernetes will inform pods that they are about to be killed and provide a window (30s I think) to gracefully terminate before it is killed. During this window your service can create another pod on a different node to take over from the one being killed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!

So how ist this "transfer" made? Doesn't the *application*  that's running on the pod/container, need to have a logic to get through this process of transferring from container-engine on node1 to container-engine on node2 ?

Comment: As far as Kubernetes is concerned there's no transfer, the pod is killed on one node, and restarted on another. So if there is some sort of logic required to pickup a job where it left off on the other node then this has to be handled by the applicaiton.